# Bound checking and integer overflow

Tags: c

The problem is very simple: given `start_index` and `count`, I want to see if the combinations can be used to safely accessed an array with `length` elements. What I have for the time being is the following:

```
uint32_t start_index = (value from somewhere);
uint32_t count = (value from somewhere);
uint32_t length = (value set earlier);
char *array = (memory allocated earlier);

if(start_index + count < length) {
    // access array starting at start_index
} else {
    // bailout
}
```

The check is, of course, inadequate since `start_index + count` can exceed the maximum possible value for an uint32_t and wrap around to a small value. To fix this, I wonder if it's more efficient to promote the variables to 64 bit or put in a second condition `start_index + count > start_index`. Or perhaps there's some other clever way to handle this?

Comment: There is a long list of methods to detect integer overflows before or after the fact [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid overflows by doing things a bit differently: first check that `count` is smaller than `length` (bail out otherwise), then you can safely compare `start_index` with `length - count`.

Comment: 2 people don't see an off by one error here. Come on, `count` smaller than OR EQUAL `length`.

Comment: If `length == count`, the original code (assuming no overflow issues) would bail out. My suggestion would bail out too. So I don't believe there is an OBOE here.